# Can I configure a transparent terminal over my wallpaper?

Tags: command-line, configuration

Can I make a transparent terminal wallpaper on my desktop?

I've done this in the past but can't remember what I did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

by [Damien](http://maketecheasier.com/author/Damien_Oh) - [HowTo] Set Terminal As a Transparent Wallpaper In Your Ubuntu Desktop

**Configuring the Terminal Profile**

The profile allows you to configure how your Terminal behaves and looks.

Open up your Terminal (Applications->Accessories->Terminal).

Create a new profile (File->New Profile).

Set trans as the profile name.

Under the **General** tab,

- uncheck the box “Show menubar by default in new terminals“

Under the **Title and Command** tab

- Set “Dynamically-set title” as “Isn’t displayed”

Under the **Color** tab

- Uncheck the box “Use colors from system theme“. Ignore the Built-In schemes dropdown box. Select the text color that you want it to display on your desktop. Make sure that it is not the same color as your current desktop wallpaper

Under the **Effects** tab

- Select “Transparent background” and drag the slider to “None“

Under the **Scrolling** tab

- In the “Scrollbar is” drop down box, select “disabled“

That’s all. Click close to exit.

**Configuring via the Compiz Way**

Install CCSM

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Open up your CCSM (System->Preferences -> Advanced Desktop Effects Setting).

1. Under **Utility** (click the Utility option on the left), activate Regex Matching (by placing a check on the box).
2. Under **Effect**,  activate Windows Decoration. Click on it to enter its configuration page. Under the Decoration windows field, enter !title=trans. Click Back.
3. Under the **Window Management**, activate Window Rules and Place Window

   - In the Window Rules configuration page, enter title=trans in the following fields ‘Skip taskbar‘, ‘skip pager‘, ‘Below‘, ‘Sticky‘. ‘Non-resizable windows‘, ‘non-minimizable windows‘, ‘non-maximizable window‘ and ‘non-closable windows‘. In the ‘Size rules‘ tab. Select New and enter the following:

[image]

Feel free to adjust the width and the height to match your desktop size.

- In the Place Window configuration page, under the Fixed Window Placement tab, select New and enter the following:

[image]

This will fix the window on the top left hand corner of your desktop (You can use Alt+Left mouse click to move the terminal around)

Close the CCSM. You are done with the configuration. To activate the terminal wallpaper, Press Alt-F2 and enter the following command:

```
gnome-terminal -–window-with-profile=trans
```

Configuring via the devilspie way (if your computer does not supports Compiz)

Install devilspie

```
sudo apt-get install devilspie
```

Create the devilspie directory and edit the configuration file.

```
mkdir ~/.devilspie
gedit ~/.devilspie/trans.ds
```

Enter the following code inside the text editor

```
(if
(matches (window_name) "trans")
(begin
(set_workspace 1)
(below)
(undecorate)
(skip_pager)
(skip_tasklist)
(wintype "utility")
(geometry "+0+0")
(geometry "1280x50")
)
)
```

and save it.

Press Alt-F2, enter

```
devilspie
```

Press Alt-F2 again

```
gnome-terminal –window-with-profile=trans
```

Done.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-create-a-transparent-terminal-session-as-your-desktop-background.html

The app is called devilspie

Answer (score 1):

There's a screenlet that does that too, much easier than having to redo your entire compiz :)

http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Terminal+Screenlet?content=74844