# Use a calendar as desktop wallpaper

Tags: desktop-background, calendar

Is it possible to use a calendar as a desktop wallpaper (it could be a simple calendar application pinned to the desktop)?

I am hoping for something looking like this:

[image]

Ideally the calendar should sync to Google calendars.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Install [dates](http://packages.ubuntu.com/dates) [image: Install dates]
2. Open Dates
3. In **Calendar > Properties > create new**

   [image] Provide the link to ical (.ics) calendar; remove `https://`
4. install [compizconfig-settings-manager](http://packages.ubuntu.com/compizconfig-settings-manager) [image: Install compizconfig-settings-manager]
5. Open **Startup Applications**
6. Add
   [image: Name: Dates; Command: dates; Comment: Dates callendar application]
7. Open **CompizConfig Settings Manager**
8. Go to **Window Management -> Window Rules**

   [image]
9. In Size rules (adjust to your monitor) [image]
10. Go to **Window Management -> Place Windows -> Fixed Window Placement**
11. Under Windows with fixed positions  *(you might want to set `Y = 24`(task-bar height), to show the menu bar)*

    [image]

*Thank you Kory Wnuk for the inspiration [your answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47747/terminal-as-a-transparent-wallpaper/47756#47756) gave me.*

Comment: I followed the instructions above using the "dates" application. However, "dates" seems to have got my time zone incorrectly always. Is this a known bug ? The times in evolution calendar works fine though. Thanks
Raajay

Answer (score 4):

**using conky and gcalcli**

[image]

One way is to use conky to do that task. [Here's a tutorial for it](http://ubuntuguide.net/display-google-calendar-on-ubuntu-desktop-using-conky).

Basically it says to use `gcalcli` to connect to your Google calendar, and use the `.conkyrc` script there to display it. you can change fonts and colors in that file too.

There's a more detailed [Ubuntu forums thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=818053) about it.

Comment: With recent gcalci and Conky, the setup is a bit different: https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/11/how-to-embed-google-calendar-on-your.html

Answer (score 4):

You could use [Rainlendar](http://rainlendar.net)

The normal version is free; the version including network synced calendars costs ~10€. I got to say, though, those 10€ a couple years ago rank among my best value-for-money purchases ever.

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to change the calendar size? I can't find the option.

Comment: You can adjust some things in Options-Skins. Choose the element of the active skin you want to modify, hit `Settings`, and see what's there. For example, the Event list has width and height parameters.

Comment: Also, there's a scale parameter available.