# Calendar as wallpaper

Tags: multiple-monitors, compiz, desktop-background

I have been searching for the past 2 weeks for a way to add a calendar as my wallpaper. I came across this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/77065/use-a-calendar-as-desktop-wallpaper) this morning and thought I would give it a shot. I swapped the date program with California and it worked perfectly on my single monitor laptop.

However, when I plugged in my external monitory to make it a dual monitor setup, it got shifted and no longer looks right.

[image: single monitor]

[image: double monitor]

Is there a way to have it work both single and dual monitors?

Comment: Is it really wallpaper (ie image file) or is it an application running in a large window?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix It's a running application, as described in the linked post.

Comment: @ByteCommander sorry I missed that first time around. So shouldn't the title say "maximized window" instead of "wallpaper"?

Comment: @basketball Does it need to be that application and does it need to be interactive, or would a real wallpaper that automatically updates itself based on your calendar data be good too?

Comment: But then it definitely is no wallpaper but an application with somehow specially configured window placement...