# gnome shell terminal

Tags: command-line, gnome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I configure a transparent terminal over my wallpaper?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47747/can-i-configure-a-transparent-terminal-over-my-wallpaper)

I was wondering if it is it possible to embed a fully transparent terminal, without menu or border shadows, to the desktop as a gnome-shell extension? I have followed some online forums and instructions given, but the do nt work, as they are either using compiz or eyecandy screenlets. under gnome 3 I found no solutions.
I'm using ubuntu 12.04 with gnome-shell.
thx

P.S. why is the topic closed? I've checked all other similar topics, not one deals with the terminal being a gnome shell extension. It's either a screenlet(which doesn't work on gnome-shell), devilspie(again doesn't work for me on 12.04 with gnome-shell) or CCSM.
So my question then is how to embed(by this I mean not a transparent movable window, but a immovable extension) it on gnome-shell.